# Is the resolution of HoloLens 2 really 2048*1080?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I created a canvas with Render Mode **Screen Space - Camera** and UI Scale Mode **Scale With Screen Size**. Then I set the Reference Resolution to 2048 * 1080.
[canvas settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vgcJ.jpg)

I put a circular ring in the upper right corner of the canvas. However, after deploying the project, part of the ring is obscured in HoloLens.
[canvas in unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3whjF.jpg)
[canvas in HoloLens 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/783ga.jpg)

So I want to know if the resolution of HoloLens 2 is really 2048 * 1080, or if there is a mistake in my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HoloLens 2 is set to the maximum render target size, which is 1440x936, by default. For more information please see:[Supported resolutions on HoloLens 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/platform-capabilities-and-apis/rendering#supported-resolutions-on-hololens-2)

Answer (score 0):

No it`s not. Formula to take Rigth Canvas size for Hololens is:
Set size of WorldSpace Canvas to 490 278 and set position to 0,0,z
You need to multiply V3 scale by this formula scale(x,y,z)=z*0.00415f